# Why img tag has no src value after parsing with jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup, html-parsing

I Want to get src value from html img tag .
by chrome and inside of inspect element i can see value of src ,but when i parse it with jsoup library, src has no value , here's my code :

```
document = Jsoup.connect("http://estelam.rahvar120.ir/index.jsp? 
pageid=2371666&p=1").userAgent(USERAGENT).method(Connection.Method.GET)
.execute().parse();

Element element = document.select("img[id=capimg]").first(); //img 
tag element
String absoluteUrl = element.absUrl("src"); // absoluteUrl = ""
String srcValue = element.attr("src"); // srcValue = ""
```

the website isn't reachable from other countries, but where I want to parse from html is :

```
<img id="capimg" alt="Enter Captcha :" 
src="" width="200" height="60">
```

The Problem is that jsoup get html content right before javascript set src value, What Should I Do ?

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the HTML you are trying to parse?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp thanks ,changes applied . is it useful ?

Comment: Tested your code with the HTML you shared, but it seems to work with `element.attr("src");`. But your image has an empty src tag.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp yes , by inspect element its viewable but in view-source and after parsing with jsoup . src has no value .

Comment: If the src url is set via JavaScript, Jsoup is not able to parse that.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp what can i do in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

The problem you are facing is not resolvable with Jsoup because Jsoup is a HTML parser not a browser. And since it's not a browser, any content rendered by javascript will not be rendered with Jsoup.

What you need is another tool that simulates web browser such as [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

There are multiple way to do this.

1. Use Selenium to handle page retrieval and **scraping**.
2. Use Selenium to get the dynamic pages and use JSoup to parse and **scrape** the content.

I personally recommend 2nd approach because I am more comfortable using Jsoup to **scrape**.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(